# Extjs multiselect combo

Tags: javascript, extjs

Tengo creado un combo con valores que obtengo de una tabla de la base de datos mediante un id. Necesito que ese combo sea de selección múltiple pero cuando pongo en el `xtype:'multiselect'` no me muestra ningún valor.

```
xtype : 'multiselect',
    fieldLabel: this.i18n.fieldSintomas,
    hiddenName  : 'fovaPsicoSintomas',
    displayField: 'valoNombre',
    valueField  : 'valoId',
    typeAhead: true,        
    forceSelection: true,
    titleCollapse: true,
    triggerAction: 'all',               
      store: new Ext.data.JsonStore({
        url : ctx + '/valores.do',
            autoLoad : false,
            remoteSort : false,
                baseParams : {
                    op : 'listByEntidad',
                        entiId : 97
                        },
                        sortInfo : {
                            field : "valoNombre",
                            direction : "ASC"
                        },
                        fields : ['valoId', 'valoNombre']               
                    })
```

Con el parámetro `entiId` lo que hago es obtener los valores de la tabla que contengan ese Id para poder mostrarlos en mi combo.

Comment: ¿Estás importando `Ext.ux.form.MultiSelect`?

Comment: No. Ya que es una clase ya predefinida y estoy haciendo modificaciones sobre ella.Voy a intentar importar lo que me has indicado. Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No basta con cambiar el `xtype` a "multiselect", también debes importar el código (JavaScript y CSS) de las MultiSelects para que funcione:

```
Ext.require([
    ...
    'Ext.ux.form.MultiSelect',
    ...
]);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda. Me ha sido muy útil!

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo este multiselect de bootstrap. Es muy bueno. http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/
Te recomiendo insertar las opciones con jquery en el onload del documento o en la respuesta del ajax. Solo debes leer un poco la documentación de la api para agregar /eliminar los items y refrescar el combo. Espero te sea util. Saludos.

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda!